# how to improve accuracy of the following logistic regression code, which tests the accuracy using 10-fold cross-validation tchnique

Tags: r, matlab, machine-learning, regression, logistic-regression

How to improve accuracy of the following logistic regression code, which tests the accuracy using 10-fold cross-validation technique.I have implemented this code using `glmfit` and `glmval`. The desired accuracy is somewhat higher and it requires the parameters to be found using maximum likelihood estimator. 
Also when I run this code in matlab I get the following error:

> Warning: X is ill conditioned, or the model is overparameterized, and
>   some coefficients are not identifiable.  You should use caution in
>   making predictions.  In glmfit at 245 In LR at 8

```
function LR( X,y)
y(y==-1)=0;
X=[ones(size(X,1),1) X];
disp(size(X,2));
indices = crossvalind('Kfold',y,10);
for i = 1:10
    test = (indices == i); train = ~test;
    b = glmfit(X(train,:),y(train),'binomial','logit');
    y_hat= glmval(b,X(test,:),'logit');
    y_true=y(test,:);
    error(i)=mean(abs(y_true-y_hat));
end
accuracy=(1-error)*100;
fprintf('accuracy= %f +- %f\n',mean(accuracy),std(accuracy));
end
```

please help

Comment: Perhaps this is the place to ask this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/ or http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Or else ask at http://stats.stackexchange.com/